# Find two words in a word?

Tags: split, logic, double

I want to know the best practise of finding two words in a single word.

Example, if I want to split "Stackoverflow" it should find that "Stack" is one word and "Overflow" is a another word. How can I do this by logic? I do program both in PHP and C#, so if you already have a codesnippet that do thesame thing, please share it.

You can also just giv a hint, how I should do.

I don't want to have a libary with different words, it should find it anyway.

Another example is "Googleplex" => "Google" + "Plex".

Thanks in advance! :)

Best regards,
Mikael

Comment: You can't do this "by logic", you must use a dictionary.

Comment: Think about it; the reason that you know that "stackoverflow" contains two words is because you have a "dictionary" in your head of all the words you've ever heard. That's the only reason you can do this. So to ask a computer to do this, it also needs a dictionary. If you did not know that *stack* was a word, you wouldn't be able to figure out that *stackoverflow* is stack + overflow. Neither can the computer!

Answer (score 2):

There is no logic regarding natural languages. Unless you can rely on "markers" such as camel-case ("StackOverflow" - each uppercase letter indicating beginning of a new word), you will have to use libraries/dictionaries which contain the knowledge about the natural language (English in this case).

Comment: Even dictionaries might not be enough.  Consider the word "pinching" -- which is not *really* "pin" + "ching", and shouldn't be parsed as such.

Comment: It is not a question of "enough" or "sufficient". It is a decision about a convention for such cases that suits your application requirements. Consider the German words "Tee" (=tea) and "Nager" (=rodent), but in German the word "Teenager" is widely used, too. Now, the convention could be to use the longest word (1 hit), or all valid words (3 hits). (Sorry for the German example, but i couldn't come up with one in English.)

Comment: Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious

Comment: @ryyker: Nice find. And sticking with my tradition of German examples: superkalifragilistischexpiallegorisch   ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have probably already done this, but in the event you have not, there are many efforts published, blogged, and otherwise interested in the same thing you are. Here are a few links:

***[SO - algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456542/what-algorithms-are-used-for-seaching-subwords-in-words)***
***[SO - Python subwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933741/python-find-all-subwords-that-can-be-found-inside-of-a-word)***
***[Java - subwordfinder](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~drum/cs1112/hw/ex7/ex7.html)*** I know Java is not your listed criteria, but the algorithms referenced on this page may answer your question
***[Java - KPM algorithm](http://tekmarathon.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/algorithm-to-find-substring-in-a-string-kmp-algorithm/)***
***[VITERBI ALGORITHM - Paper on subword unit](http://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/spr/publications/Gerber:11.pdf)***  (heavy on theory, light on technique)

The thing each of these has in common is the use of some form of externally referenced ruleset, i.e a dictionary or similar.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without a dictionary depot this is plainly just ***impossible.***

Say you have a word.. forAmerica.. Programs understand `for` as a keyword but not as the real word **for**. You need to educate it with using dictionaries or hashmaps/arraylists

Comment: "It's impossible" is a useless answer, til you mention *why* it's impossible.

Comment: Gave a slight explanation.

Comment: No, in general programs don't understand "for" as a keyword. Only compilers and interpreters do.